# C Processes Programming

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

I'm taking an Operating Systems class for university and we have an assignment as follows:

*Write a program that can be used to create a child process.
The child process should create a file called “Listx.txt” and ask the user for data to write to it. The parent process should read the data from the file and display it on the screen.
Modify the program to make the parent read the file and display the contents five times. It should pause for 1 second between each display.
Modify the program to make the parent read the file and display the contents over and over again until the user sends SIGSTOP. It should pause for 1 second between each display.*

And this is the code I've come up with:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
int main()
{
    int x;
    int y = 0;
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid==0)
    {
        printf("Hi, i am the child\n");
        int fd;
        fd = open("listx.txt", O_RDWR |O_CREAT |O_TRUNC);
        printf ("enter Number");
        scanf("%d\n",x);
        char wd [100];
        ssize_t nr;
        wd[0]=x;
        nr = write (fd, wd, sizeof (wd));
    }
    else
        printf(" I am the parent, the child is %d\n",pid);
    {
        int fd;
        fd = open ("listx.txt", O_RDONLY);
        if (fd == -1)
        {
            printf("file not opened \n"); 
        }
        else
        {
            printf("file found \n"); 
        }
        char wd[100];
        ssize_t nr;
        nr = read (fd, wd, sizeof (wd));
        if (nr == -1)
        {
            printf("file not read \n"); 
        }
        else
        {
            while (y < 5){
                printf("The file has %s \n",wd);
                sleep(1);
            }
        }
return 0;
```

The program compiles (through GCC) but I think I have the logic wrong.
May you kindly assist with helping me solve this?

Comment: Have you decided on the programming language yet?

Comment: Could you kindly repost with a more normal formatting? It will be easier to read then and you'll attract more helpers. I'd rather get a coffee than look at your code in its current form.

Comment: @DanielDaranas yes, the assignment is required to be done in C. Sorry I didn't specify the language.

Comment: You should correct the code you've posted, because there are syntax errors at multiple locations.

Comment: When dealing with simple files, why not use `fopen/fread/fwrite`? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
scanf("%d\n",x);
char wd [100];
ssize_t nr;
wd[0]=x;
```

is rather wrong, in more ways than one:

1. You must pas `&x` to `scanf()`, since it can't store the value unless given an address. Instead you pass the current value of `x`, causing undefined behavior.
2. You assign the value of `x` into a single character, which is going to drop lots of bits. This is probably not what you want to do.
3. You use file descriptors even after detecting that they are not valid.

Please figure out how to maximize the diagnostics (warnings and errors) from your compiler, and observe what it says. Many of these problems will generate warnings. For GCC, [this manual page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) is informative. Basically, start out by adding `-Wall -Wpedantic -Wextra` to your compiler invocation.

Comment: Thank you for your useful and informative input. I'll keep this in mind. I've noticed the scanf() problem I've used, let me try correct this now. :)

Answer (score 0):

- exit the child (`_exit(0)`)
- wait in the parent until child has finished (`waitpid(2)` et.al.)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Will incorporate this :)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from scanf problems I see `printf(" I am the parent, the child is %d\n",pid);` that I suspect that you wanted inside the curly brackets.
Moreover **you need to ensure that the child wrote before starting reading** so the first instruction in the parent  should be `waitpid(pid,&status,0);` that waits for the child termination (and indirectly for the file being written). Note that the fact that the code of the child is on top doesn't mean that it will executed as first (I think this is what the exercise wants to highlight).
Another thing that  you should always do as a good programmer is closing your file after writing.

Comment: @Bathsheba As you are editing the file could you move the printf inside the "{"?